# JQuery & Javascript anchor link top offset for different page link

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor, offset

I have the following working script from CSS Tricks, I have adjusted it to have a top offset, due to a fixed header menu:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 180
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
Link in the header menu
<a href="/subpage#about">About</a>

Link on the subpage
<a name="about"></a>
```

On the same page, the scrolling with top offset works fine, however when there is a link to an anchor link on a different page, the top offset is ignored. How can I fix that?

Comment: can you please post the html css code as well?

Comment: added the code :-)